# Split comma separated string into multiple values using xslt

Tags: xslt

I need to split two tags with comma separated string into a list of parent-child tags as shown below.

For example, the input will be :-

```
<UserID>162,163</UserID>
<UserName>Stacy,Stephen</UserName>
```

Expected output :-
[Expected Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUVT6.png)
Please help to achieve this result using xslt code

---

I tried the following format which I got from another query, but its generating a nested pattern instead of the list :-

```
<xsl:template name="tokenize">
    <xsl:param name="textID" select="."/>
    <xsl:param name="textName" select="."/>
    <xsl:param name="separator" select="','"/>
  <User>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="not(contains($textID, $separator))">
        <ID>
          <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($textID)"/>
        </ID>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <ID>
          <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(substring-before($textID, $separator))"/>
        </ID>
        <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
          <xsl:with-param name="textID" select="substring-after($textID, $separator)"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="textName" select="substring-after($textName, $separator)"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="not(contains($textName, $separator))">
        <Name>
          <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($textName)"/>
        </Name>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <Name>
          <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(substring-before($textName, $separator))"/>
        </Name>
        <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
          <xsl:with-param name="textID" select="substring-after($textID, $separator)"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="textName" select="substring-after($textName, $separator)"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </User>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Please show us a bit of what you have tried and where you are stuck. http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Comment: I can't believe you don't find this on Google.

Comment: Always say which version of XSLT you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few assumptions before simplifying the `tokenize` template shared in the XSLT code.

1. The count of `comma` separated values in `<UserID>` and `<UserName>` is always equal.
2. There is a 1-1 correspondence on the indexes of the values i.e. `162 <-> Stacy` and `163 <-> Stephen`.
3. XSLT version is 1.0
4. A parent node `<UserList>` has been added as a root node for the shared input XML.

XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
     <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

     <xsl:template match="UserList">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
                <xsl:with-param name="textID" select="normalize-space(UserID)" />
                <xsl:with-param name="textName" select="normalize-space(UserName)" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:copy>
     </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="tokenize">
        <xsl:param name="textID" />
        <xsl:param name="textName" />
        <xsl:param name="separator" select="','" />

        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="not(contains($textID, $separator) and contains($textName, $separator)) ">
                <User>
                    <ID><xsl:value-of select="$textID" /></ID>
                    <Name><xsl:value-of select="$textName" /></Name>
                </User>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <User>
                    <ID><xsl:value-of select="substring-before($textID, $separator)" /></ID>
                    <Name><xsl:value-of select="substring-before($textName, $separator)" /></Name>
                </User>
                <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
                    <xsl:with-param name="textID" select="normalize-space(substring-after($textID, $separator))" />
                    <xsl:with-param name="textName" select="normalize-space(substring-after($textName, $separator))" />
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output

```
<UserList>
    <User>
        <ID>162</ID>
        <Name>Stacy</Name>
    </User>
    <User>
        <ID>163</ID>
        <Name>Stephen</Name>
    </User>
</UserList>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Aniket V. I'm able to derive the intended output using this template.